# How to make Grub display after installing Ubuntu on a laptop with Windows OS?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, partitioning

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 on a laptop, but whenever I turn on my computer, it still boots to Windows and GRUB doesn't seem to be working at all.

My partition scheme is as follows:

- /dev/sda1 - Some NTFS partition for Lenovo recovery or something labeled SYSTEM_DRV (this has the Windows boot flag on it)
- /dev/sda2 - My NTFS Windows partition
- /dev/sda3 - My extended partition containing:

  - /dev/sda5 - / partition, ext4, 20 GB
  - /dev/sda6 - swap partition, linux-swap, 3 GB
  - /dev/sda7 - /home, ext4, 450 GB
- /dev/sda4 - Another partition that is useful for Lenovo recovery or something labeled LENOVO_PART.

The point is, I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 according to this scheme via the LiveUSB environment, but whenever I turn on my computer, the motherboard BIOS screen is shown, and then it jumps right to Windows and GRUB is skipped completely.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You probably installed grub to the thumbdrive, not the system drive.  See what happens if you boot with the thumbdrive plugged in and update with results.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot to your live disk
2. Open `gparted`
3. Right click on `/dev/sda5`
4. Click 'Manage Flags'
5. Set the `boot` flag (same thing as the `active` flag in windows)

Grub should now load if it is actually installed on `/dev/sda5`